# Issue compiling program utilizing pthread.h

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, header-files

I am trying to compile the following program on a Linux (Ubuntu) machine:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int sum; /* this data is shared by the thread(s) */
void *runner(void *param); /* threads call this function */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
pthread t tid; /* the thread identifier */
pthread attr t attr; /* set of thread attributes */
if (argc != 2) {
fprintf(stderr,"usage: a.out <integer value>\n");
return -1;
}
if (atoi(argv[1]) < 0) {
fprintf(stderr,"%d must be >= 0\n",atoi(argv[1]));
return -1;
}
/* get the default attributes */
pthread attr init(&attr);
/* create the thread */
pthread create(&tid,&attr,runner,argv[1]);
/* wait for the thread to exit */
pthread join(tid,NULL);
printf("sum = %d\n",sum);
}
/* The thread will begin control in this function */
void *runner(void *param)
{
int i, upper = atoi(param);
sum = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= upper; i++)
sum += i;
pthread exit(0);
}
```

However whenever I try to do so:
*gcc -o runner runner.c* 
I get an error "Unknown type name 'pthread'.
Now I've been looking around and see I have to include -lpthread:
*gcc -o runner runner.c -lpthread* 
However it produces the very same error.

I've run the following command: *whereis pthread* and it returns the file location so I know i have the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing some underscores.  `pthread t` should be `pthread_t`, `pthread_attr_t` should be `pthread_attr_t` etc.